# start-server-and-test not starting test cases after starting the test server

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-node

I am trying to use [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) npm package and want to run test cases.
For this I first need to start a test server and then run test command.
This how my `package.json` script part looks like.

Now the issue is start-server-and-test is starting the test server but it's not starting the test cases.

```
{
...
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand --config jest.config.json",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**' --ext 'ts,js' --exec \"ts-node src/app.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node src/app.ts",
    "test-server": "MYSQL_TABLE_PREFIX=TEST_ PORT=4001 ts-node src/app.ts",
    "ci": "start-server-and-test 'yarn test-server' http://localhost:4001/ 'yarn test'"
  },
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So I figured out that the issue was my endpoint `http://localhost:4001/` was not responding with 200 status code and due to this the command `yarn test` was not getting executed.
So then I changed the endpoint to `http://localhost:4001/health` which was giving a 200 status code and then the test cases were getting executed.

so now the package.json looks like this

```
{
...
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand --config jest.config.json",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**' --ext 'ts,js' --exec \"ts-node src/app.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node src/app.ts",
    "test-server": "MYSQL_TABLE_PREFIX=TEST_ PORT=4001 ts-node src/app.ts",
    "ci": "start-server-and-test 'yarn test-server' http://localhost:4001/health 'yarn test'"
  },
...
...
}
```